# Makefile GNU Make 4.1 check if directory exist

Tags: makefile, directory, mingw, gnu

Trying to check if a directory exists for my Makefile. Unfortunately, I found out the difference between different versions of Make.

To check the directory I'm using:

```
if [ -d "D:/MKS" ]; then \
        echo.exe "MKS project already exists."; exit 1; \
fi
```

Using version 'GNU Make 4.1.90 Built for Windows32' it is fine.
With version 'GNU Make 4.1 Built for i686-w64-mingw32' I have in our general GNU tool folder it does not work. Getting this error:

```
-d was unexpected at this time.
makefile_qac.mk:157: recipe for target 'qac_init' failed
```

I tried D:/MKS or D:\MKS or D:/MKS/ or "D:/MKS" .. any possible combinations ... not help.
Was there some significant change between version 4.1.9 and 4.1.

Version 4.1.9 is built-in the Eclipse environment so I can not use it separately. And I want to run the build process just from the command line, not from the Eclipse.

Comment: In the instance that works, `make` is invoking a POSIX shell to run commands.  In the instance that doesn't work, `make` is invoking the Windows `cmd.exe` shell to run commands.  You can't run POSIX shell commands in Windows `cmd.exe`.  The most likely reason for the difference is that when you run the "working" version there's a `sh.exe` on your path, and when you run the "non-working" version there is not.

Comment: The "working" version is running over the Eclipse as a make target. The "not working" version is just my BAT file initializing PATHS to all necessary tools together with Make.exe. So how I can 'force' the make to use sh.exe and not cmd.exe for these makefile comamnds?

Comment: I don't do Windows so I'm not sure but my understanding is that make will use `sh.exe` by default if it can be found.  Apparently whatever you're doing to "initialize PATHS" is not sufficient: either you're removing a path or Eclipse is adding one.  You'll have to find out which.  One thing you can do is in your makefile, add this: `$(info PATH = $(PATH))` to the top and see what it prints when Eclipse runs, versus when your BAT file runs it, and figure out where `sh.exe` is.

Comment: One thing you can do is add `SHELL := sh.exe` to your Makefile.  If you do that then it will never use `cmd.exe`.  But, if it can't find `sh.exe` you'll get an error saying that it can't be found.  That error might be more understandable.  Or not.

Comment: One possible way out is to use `MKS_PRESENT := $(wildcard D:/MKS/.)` to test for the directory independently from the shell. If you want to have it run only inside a recipe, this won't work however - only at the beginning, or at a global level.